# why does this argument in proof of cheeger's hold?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

$$ \lambda \geq \frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} [(u_i-u_j)^2 + (v_i-v_j)^2]}{ \sum_i d_i(u_i+v_i)^2 }$$

And then they say since $$\frac{a+b}{c+d} \geq \min \{\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{d}\}$$ it suffices to show that $$\frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} (u_i-u_j)^2}{ \sum_i d_i u_i^2 }\geq \frac{h^2_G}{2}$$ where $h_G$ is the Cheeger constant.

**Now here are my questions...**

I don't understand why $$\frac{a+b}{c+d} \geq \min \{\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{d}\}$$ is true nor do I see why this implies we can just show $$\frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} (u_i-u_j)^2}{ \sum_i d_i u_i^2 }\geq \frac{h^2_G}{2}.$$ To further elaborate, how is it true that $$\frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} (u_i-u_j)^2}{ \sum_i d_i u_i^2 } \leq \frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} (v_i-v_j)^2}{ \sum_i d_i(2u_i v_i + v_i^2) }$$
and thus
$$\frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} [(u_i-u_j)^2 + (v_i-v_j)^2]}{ \sum_i d_i(u_i+v_i)^2 }\geq \frac{ \sum_{(i,j)\in E} (u_i-u_j)^2}{ \sum_i d_i u_i^2 }$$ because these would need to hold in order to apply $\frac{a+b}{c+d} \geq \min \{\frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{d}\}$ to begin with.

Comment: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos521/oldeigenval.pdf

Taken from this link.

Comment: For the first question: if $\frac{a}{c}\geq \frac{b}{d} $ then $\frac{a}{c}\geq\frac{a+b}{c+d} \geq \frac{b}{d} $, this can be proven easily by calclations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

- In order to prove that $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\geq min \left\{\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{d}\right\} $, you can assume that: $\frac{a}{c}\geq \frac{b}{d}$ which signifies that $ad\geq bc$ and this implies $ad+bd\geq bc+bd$ hence $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\geq\frac{b}{d} $
- Because $y_i=u_i+v_i$ and $u_iv_i=0$ we have $(u_i+v_i)^2=u_i^2+v_i^2$ , so you just forget that $u_iv_i=0$

Hope this clarifies your problems.

Comment: $ad+bd \geq ad+bc$ does not imply $\frac{a+b}{c+d}\geq \frac{b}{d}$.

Comment: Did you mean $ad+bd\geq bd+bc$?

Comment: @ClarkKent , yes I corrected it, is that helpful?

Comment: Yes this helps. And then the latter part (showing the expression with $u_i$ and $u_j$) is because we can do a symmetry argument since we can always flip the signs of the components of $y$ to go from $u_i$ to $v_i$.

Comment: yes exactly because of the symmetry between $u_i$ and $v_i$ we need just to prove it for one of them, because the same prove works for the other one.

Comment: If this answers your question you can accept it otherwise what is wrong that i have to improve?